# Why does the clip doesn't stop?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make music play with one button(First click is play, second is stop, third is play again etc etc). The problem is it does not want to stop. Second click is blank and then third music starts to impose itself. Any suggestions?

```java
public void music() {
    File file = new File("music.wav");
    AudioInputStream audioStream = null;
    Clip clip = null;
    try {
        audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
        clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clip.open(audioStream);
    } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    if (m % 2 == 1) {
        clip.start();
        m++;
    } else {
        clip.stop();
        m++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `m` and where does it come from?

Comment: I declared 'm' right after the main class starts.                                                               
It is accessible from the start, it does work because my second click is blank just it doent stop the clip

Comment: Think carefully about the logic of the code. What exactly do you expect `clip = AudioSystem.getClip();` to do? (Did you try to check the documentation?) Will you get the same `clip` every time you call that? Therefore, if you call it a second time and then call `.stop` on the result, will that stop the clip that you got the first time?

Comment: I see, so how should I approach it?

Comment: Did you try remembering a `clip` instance between calls (for example, the same way that `m` is remembered)? You may want to do some setup work only the first time that `music` is called (unless you would rather do it when the instance of your class is created). Perhaps you can think of an easy way to tell whether `music` has ever been called before (hint: what would `clip` be the first time? What would it be every other time?)

Answer (score 0):

```java
public void playmusic() {
    if(m%2==1) {
        File file = new File("music.wav");
        AudioInputStream audioStream = null;
        try {
            audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
            clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(audioStream);
        } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        clip.start();
        m++;
    }
    else {
        clip.stop();
        m++;
    }
}
```

I did it like this, thanks for helping Karl. To be honest it still feels overly complicated. I just don't know the tools to do it better.

Comment: Well if your Exception are all going to do the same thing you can also bundle them together with `(LineUnavailableException | UnsupportedAudioFileException  | IOException e)` as well, since you want to simplify it

Comment: OT: `m` should be a `boolean` instead of a number.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).